# How to Evaluate this Series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n+1}(1+2^n)}{n2^n}$?

Tags: complex-analysis, power-series

I have to study complex series

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n+1}(1+2^n)}{n2^n}$$

and prove that series is equal to $\log(3)$. That series I have to stady in the circumference $C(0,R)$ and give $R$. OK, I have tried express like sum of two complex power series where $z=-1$, in that, I studied the convergence $R_1$ and $R_2$ and I suposse that $R=\min\{R_1,R_2\}$, because the set of convergence is the insersection of set of convergence of sum one and sum two. It is correct?

I do not know if what I am do it is correct... and I do not have idea how can i prove that the series is $\log (3)$... Help

Comment: Why do you say that this is a Complex Series? I see all numbers in Real.

Comment: "the set of convergence is the insersection of set of convergence of sum one and sum two": in general, the set of convergence is _at least_ the intersection of the two sets of convergence. It may be larger.

Comment: naeioi that you see all number in Real it is not mean that you can see like complex. @TonyK so if I divide the series I do not get nothing concrete about the radio of my serie... I could see my serie like a power serie multiply by $z^n$ where z=1 and calculate its radio like $R=\frac{1}{lim \frac{C_{n+1}}{C_n}}$ ? where $C_n=\frac{(-1)^{n+1}(1+2^n)}{n2^n}$

Comment: In this case, you can treat the two parts separately, because both parts converge. I was just pointing out that your claim is not always true.

Answer (score 4):

To get the value, split the sum, use the [Taylor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_logarithm#Derivative.2C_Taylor_series) series for $\ln(1+x)$ (also known as [Mercator series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mercator_series)) and the [alternating harmonic series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_series_(mathematics)#Alternating_harmonic_series): 
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n+1}(1+2^n)}{n2^n}
=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n2^n}+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n}= \ln\left(1+\frac{1}{2}\right)+\ln 2= \ln 3$$